# Glassfish 5.0 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, glassfish, nosuchmethoderror

When i tried connect google custom search api glassfish throw nosuchmethoderror

That's codes

```
private int conn (String search)throws Exception {

    String key="mykey";
    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q="+search+"&cx=017576662512468239146%3Aomuauf_lfve&key="+key);
    doTrustToCertificates();
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
    String splitreader = "";
    StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();
    while((splitreader = reader.readLine()) != null){
        ss.append(splitreader);
}
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(ss.toString());
    JSONObject jsonrequest = json.getJSONObject("queries").getJSONArray("request").getJSONObject(0);
    return jsonrequest.getInt("totalResults");
    }


 public void doTrustToCertificates() throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return;
                }
            }
    };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
            if (!urlHostName.equalsIgnoreCase(session.getPeerHost())) {
                System.out.println("Warning: URL host '" + urlHostName + "' is different to SSLSession host '" + session.getPeerHost() + "'.");
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
}
```

Exception

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)V

But codes worked on glassfish 4.1.1 and wildfly i can't understand why not working on glassfish 5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your Java version. This is due to changes in the JDK around JDK 8u161 which affect Grizzly.

To summarise:

- If you use GlassFish 5.0, you need to be on a version of JDK 8 **below** JDK 8u161
- If you use GlassFish 5.0.1 or higher, you need to be on a version of JDK 8 **above** 8u161

This bug is tracked in the GlassFish GitHub issue tracker:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22436

Comment: The 5.0.1 nightly builds don't seem to have valid certs. You'll need to copy the cacerts.jks and keystore.jks from the 5.0 release into your 5.0.1 domain config, e.g. `glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/`